# useState initial value don't use directly the value

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-hooks, react-typescript

I have an initial state that I never use directly in the code, only inside another set value state

Only a scratch example:

```
interface PersonProps {}

const Person: React.FC<PersonProps> = () => {
  const [name, setName] = useState<string>("")
  const [todayYear, setTodayYear] = useState<string>("")
  const [birthYear, setBirthYear] = useState<string>("")
  const [age, setAge] = useState<string>("")

  const getPerson = async () => {
    try {
      const response = await getPersonRequest()
      const data = await response.data

      setName(data.name)
      setTodayYear(data.today_year)
      setBirthYear(data.future_year)
      setAge(data.todayYear - data.birthYear)
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error)
    }
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    getPerson()
  })


  return (

    <h1>{name}</h1>
    <h2>{age}</h2>
  )

}
export default Person
```

In this case as you can see I will never use "**todayYear**" and "**birthYear**" on UI, so code give a warning

> todayYear is assigned a value but never used

What can I do to fix this and/or ignore this warning?

Comment: Just as a side comment: That age calculation will be wrong prior to the person's birthday. For instance, for me that calculation would result in 55 even though I'm "only" 54 until late this year when my birthday occurs. To make the age correct, you have to allow for whether you're doing this before or on/after the person's birthday.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you don't use them for rendering, there's no reason to have them in your state:

```typescript
const Person: React.FC<PersonProps> = () => {
    const [name, setName] = useState<string>("")
    const [age, setAge] = useState<string>("")
  
    const getPerson = async () => {
        try {
            const response = await getPersonRequest()
            const data = await response.data
      
            setName(data.name)
            setAge(data.todayYear - data.birthYear)
        } catch (error) {
            console.log(error)
        }
    }
  
    useEffect(() => {
        getPerson()
    })
  
    return (
        <h1>{name}</h1>
        <h2>{age}</h2>
    )
}
```

---

Side note: In most cases, you can leave off the type argument to `useState` wen you're providing an intial value. There's no difference between:

```typescript
const [name, setName] = useState<string>("")
```

and

```typescript
const [name, setName] = useState("")
```

TypeScript will infer the type from the argument. You only need to be explicit when inference can't work, such as if you have `useState<Thingy | null>(null)`.

---

As [this other answer points out](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66440038/157247), unless you want your code to run every time your component re-renders (which would cause an infinite render loop), you need to specify a dependency array. In this case, probably an empty one if you only want to get the person information once.

Also, since it's possible for your component to be unmounted before the async action occurs, you should cancel your person request if it unmounts (or at least disregard the result if unmounted):

```typescript
const Person: React.FC<PersonProps> = () => {
    const [name, setName] = useState<string>("");
    const [age, setAge] = useState<string>("");
  
    const getPerson = async () => {
        const response = await getPersonRequest();
        const data = await response.data;
        return data;
    };
  
    useEffect(() => {
        getPerson()
        .then(data => {
            setName(data.name)
            setAge(data.todayYear - data.birthYear)
        })
        .catch(error => {
            if (/*error is not a cancellation*/) {
                // (Probably better to show this to the user in some way)
                console.log(error);
            }
        });
        return () => {
            // Cancel the request here if you can
        };
    }, []);
  
    return (
        <h1>{name}</h1>
        <h2>{age}</h2>
    );
};
```

If it's not possible to cancel the `getPersonRequest`, the fallback is a flag:

```typescript
const Person: React.FC<PersonProps> = () => {
    const [name, setName] = useState<string>("");
    const [age, setAge] = useState<string>("");
  
    const getPerson = async () => {
        const response = await getPersonRequest();
        const data = await response.data;
        return data;
    };
  
    useEffect(() => {
        let mounted = true;
        getPerson()
        .then(data => {
            if (mounted) {
                setName(data.name)
                setAge(data.todayYear - data.birthYear)
            }
        })
        .catch(error => {
            // (Probably better to show this to the user in some way)
            console.log(error);
        });
        return () => {
            mounted = false;
        };
    }, []);
  
    return (
        <h1>{name}</h1>
        <h2>{age}</h2>
    );
};
```

Comment: Thank you so much!! This makes total sense! I'll point your answer as right :D
I'm new with React Hooks and TypeScript so thank you for the extra knowledge sharing about the types! :)))

Comment: Just in case, you should probably check if the component is still mounted before calling `setName` and `setAge` inside `getPerson` :)

Comment: @dglozano - I was *just* thinking of that because I was looking at the `useEffect` because of the other answer... :-)

Answer (score 2):

I also would like to mention one more thing. It's not related to your question but I think it's important enough to talk about it.

you need to explicitly state your dependencies for `useEffect`

In your case, you have the following code

```
useEffect(() => {
 getPerson()
})
```

it should be written as follow if you want to trigger this only one time when a component is rendered

```
useEffect(() => {
 getPerson()
}, [])
```

or if you want to trigger your side effect as a result of something that has changed

```
useEffect(() => {
 getPerson()
}, [name])
```

If this is not clear for I suggest read the following article [using the effect hook](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html)